# Blazor server generate and download file to user client

Tags: file, server, download, blazor

i want generate and create a zip file @onclick event and give that file to user via download dialog

i generate file and convert it to Base64 and Navigate user to data:application/octet-stream;base64,=3453dfg
file downloaded but not name and not extension ....

i add @onclick event in  tag and add attribute download="filename.zip"
but downloaded file not have any name and extension

my code like below :
<a download="filename.zip" @onclick="toDownload>Generate File

```
void toDownload(){
string base64fileString = generateFileBase64();
naviagationManager.navigateto("data:application/octet-stream;base64,=3453dfg");
}
```

attribute download="filename.zip" dont work ... why ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set target="_top" if you have route to file

```
     <a href="img/2.jpg" download="test.jpeg" target="_top">
            download
        </a>
```

2. Download by js. See examples by url below
   Examples:
   [1]: https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/implement-the-download-file-feature-on-a-blazor-webassembly-app-2f8p

Comment: i want serve file to user in function via @onclick event in dom

Comment: @abbas-h  I undestand you. However, in their scenario, Blazor doesn't consider the download attribute! so there are alternative ways in the article.